# How many integer numbers from 0 to 100000 contain 2 or more digits 5?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many integer numbers from 0 to 100000 contain 2 or more digits 5? I know that I need to apply some kind of formula to this problem, but I can't choose which one.

Can you please help me?

Comment: How many contain no $5's$?  How many contain exactly $1$?

Comment: not exactly one, more or equals to 2 5's, example - 55 535 553 355

Comment: I understand that.  But it's easier to work with the complement:  if your number fails to have two or more $5's$ than either it has none or exactly one.

Comment: To clarify the total count:  are you looking at integers $n$ with $0≤n≤100000$ or with $0<n<100000$?  It doesn't change the answer much, but you ought to clarify what you meant.  The posted solution from @Sarah below assumes you meant the former...if instead you meant the latter, then the $100,001$ ought to be $99,999$.

Comment: Sarah was right, including 0 and 100000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For numbers that don not contain digit 5, we have 9 options (0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9) for each digit. And we have 5 digits in total, so number of numbers that do not contain digit 5 would be $9\times 9\times 9\times 9\times 9=9^5$.

Number of numbers that contain at least one digit 5 = All numbers - Number of numbers that do not contain digit 5 = $100001-9^5$

(Note: we put $100001$ here because there's $100001$ numbers from 0 to $100000$)

Number of numbers that contain only one digit 5 = $5\times 9^4$

So, number of numbers that contain at least two digit 5 = $100001-9^5-5\times 9^4=8147$